# Why creating a cordova app does not work?

Tags: cordova

I installed apache cordova and I tried to create an app with cordova create MyApp. It failed. I get the following error:

```
cordova create MyApp
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\index.js:103
        async fetchInfo() {
              ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:19:22)
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I installed the latest version of nodejs and now cordova creates projects.